# Updating the values attribute of a table inside a JSP page after an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have problem in displaying the content of a table which will be available once an AJAX request is made on click of some row of another table in the same page.
Following is my code for the table in my JSP page.

```
<table id="previousList" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6">Previous Billing Records</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Bill Number</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <c:forEach var="lastBill" items="${previousBills}" varStatus="status">  
      <tr>
        <td>${lastBill.billingId}</td>
        <td>${lastBill.billAmount}</td>
      </tr>
    </c:forEach>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
var jsonData;
var patientTable = $('#patientsList').DataTable();
var table = document.getElementById("selectedPatient");

$('#patientsList tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
  var data = patientTable.row(this).data();
  console.log("Data " + data);

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/LoginMavenSpringMVC/billing/lastBill",
    data: "patientId=" + data[0],
    success: function(response) {
      console.log("Showing the LastBill Details: " + response);
      jsonData = response;
    },
    error: function(e) {
      alert('Error: ' + e);
    }
  });
});
```

My controller code is as follows.

```java
@RequestMapping(value="/lastBill")
public @ResponseBody String lastBill(ModelMap model, String patientId) 
{
  System.out.println("ID: " + patientId);
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  Bill b = new Bill();
  b.setBillAmount(1000);
  b.setBillingId("12345SDf");
  Collection<Bill> bills = new ArrayList<Bill>();
  bills.add(b);
  model.addAttribute("previousBills",bills);
  String jsonBills = gson.toJson(bills);
  model.addAttribute("jsonBills", jsonBills);
  return jsonBills;
}
```

I am able to get the JSON data but failed to bind the values to the table. Any suggestions/answers would be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This gets the data, but does nothing with it. Where are you actually using the `jsonData` variable?

Comment: `jsonData = response` is where the data is available from the ajax call to /lastBill. But you don't do anything with it. In your 'success' function you need to write it to the table.

Comment: Ya I am getting the response. But I am finding it difficult to fill the table with this response data.(I tried to insert the list in the controller itself as

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this it should work.

```js
var jsonData;
   
$('#patientsList tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
  var data = patientTable.row(this).data();
  console.log("Data " + data);

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/LoginMavenSpringMVC/billing/lastBill",
    data: "patientId=" + data[0],
    success: function(response) {
      console.log("Showing the LastBill Details: " + response);
      jsonData = JSON.parse(response);
    $.each(jsonData, function(i, bill) {
   var newRowContent = "<tr><td>"+bill.billingId+"</td><td>"+bill.billAmount+"</td></tr>";
    $("#previousList tbody").append(newRowContent);
         });
  
    },
    error: function(e) {
      alert('Error: ' + e);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Chandu :-) You saved me. It will work. But a small correction, only <tr><td> tags will be inside the double quotes.